# What is the idiom clearly implying "sacrifice short term, trifling objectives for long term goals!"

Tags: idioms, formality

I would like to know the answer, preferably formal, for this question:

What is the idiom clearly implying:

> sacrifice short term, trifling objectives for long term goals!

I would like to use it in TOEFL.

Further, what is the idiom that explicitly means:

> it should be accepted without compromise, or indisputably

For instance, the idea for building a hospital in a particular zone should be agreed without any hesitation, it is preposterous to disagree with such beneficial, impeccable project.

Comment: Hi Mohammed, welcome to English Language & Usage (EL&U), which is "a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts". You may not be aware of another site, [ELL.se], which might be very useful for you; it provides a "library of detailed answers to every question about learning the English language."

Comment: Regarding your question here, you've actually asked two quite different and unrelated questions. I recommend you edit your post to delete the second question and ask it as a separate, new question. This will maximise your chances of getting good answers to both. You can amend your question by clicking on the [edit] link. :-)

Comment: Well appreciated and well noted.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are referring to the concept of [***vision***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/vision).

> 2 [MASS NOUN] The ability to think about or plan the future with imagination or wisdom:
> *the organization had lost its vision and direction*

To illuminate:
*The ultimate measure of a man is not where he stands in moments of comfort and convenience, but where he stands at times of challenge and controversy.*
Martin Luther King Jr.

References:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/vision
http://biography.yourdictionary.com/articles/martin-luther-kings-vision-change-world.html

Answer (score 2):

A very common idiom for "sacrific[*ing*] short term, trifling objectives for long term goals!" is **[delayed (or deferred) gratification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed_gratification)**:

> ...the ability to resist the temptation for an immediate reward and wait for a later reward. - [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed_gratification)

In regard to "it should be accepted without compromise, or indisputably" a common idiom is [no-brainer](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/no-brainer):

> Something, especially a choice or decision, that is so obvious or easy as to require little or no thought. - [the free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/no-brainer)

or alternatively, a [must](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/must):

> *noun*
>   12.
>   something necessary, vital, or required:
>   *This law is a must*. - [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/must)

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. Thanks and appreciated

Comment: "Delayed gratification" isn't an [*idiom*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/idiom), it's a term in psychology that has an exactly literal meaning.

Comment: @chappo I see your point, but it's at least somewhat arguable, as the individual terms don't comprise in their own definitions the sense of goal-setting-and-acheiving that the phrase connotes in wider usage.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't settle for second best.**

> *second best*
>
> ​ not as good as the best and therefore not wanted as much:
>
> *She refuses to settle for second best - she strives for perfection.*

[[CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/second-best)]

Answer (score 1):

Idiom implying the "sacrifice of short term, trifling objectives for long term goals": **take the long view**.

Idiom explicitly meaning "should be accepted without compromise, or indisputably": **a given**.